# Renaming Network Interface

Tags: networking

I want to rename my wireless adapter both int&ext. By default they are named randomly;

```
  ┌─╼[~] 
  └────╼ ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 98:40:bb:43:28:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 545  bytes 70113 (70.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 545  bytes 70113 (70.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fd6f:40b0:565e::e84  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ec56:29b9:d982:cf64  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd6f:40b0:565e:0:4ce5:90a:87e1:cae8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd6f:40b0:565e:0:5a4c:704e:d968:40d2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether a8:6b:ad:77:42:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14636  bytes 17950827 (17.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11826  bytes 1675564 (1.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx00c0ca59bd42: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:c0:ca:59:bd:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to rename wlp1s0 to wlan0 and other to wlan1, there are two threads in this forum i have found but, sadly they don't apply in my case because;

1: I'm using pop_os with systemd-bootloader.

2: One of them suggested udev rule but in my `/etc/udev/rules.d/` there are no rules, there is another directory with a lot of rules, created by system but none of them contain *persistent-net.rules.

3: Someone suggested `net.ifnames=0` for grub but I'm using systemd-boot with encryption so from what I have read it is nearly impossibly to disable encryption without reinstalling.

What I have tried is to create a rules by myself (after reading some article on udev and copying some from a mellanox knowledge base post) but they don't work smh. here are my rules;

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="a8:6b:ad:77:42:5f", KERNEL=="wlp1s0", NAME="wlan0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:c0:ca:59:bd:43", KERNEL=="wlx*", NAME="wlan1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make two files in `/etc/systemd/network`, named e.g. `70-wlan0.link` and `71-wlan1.link`. Their contents should be, respectively:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=a8:6b:ad:77:42:5f

[Link]
Name=wlan0
```

and

```
[Match]
MACAddress=00:c0:ca:59:bd:42

[Link]
Name=wlan1
```

Remove your udev rules, update your initramfs file (just in case your NICs are loaded in initramfs phase), and reboot. Your interfaces should now be renamed to your specifications. See `man systemd.link` for further details.

By the way, those names are not random.

`wlp1s0` means **w**ire**l**ess device on PCI bus **p**ath: bus **1** **s**lot **0**... and since **f**unction is not specified, it is also 0. So that would be device 1:0.0 in the `lspci` listing. Likewise, `enp2s0` would be device 2:0.0.

On USB devices, a path-based name would begin with the bus and slot identifiers of the USB controller, and continue with further identifiers based on USB bus and port numbers... which could vary each time the device is plugged in. So `wlx` is the prefix for a MAC-address-based interface name for a wireless device, which stays with the device even if plugged to another port.

If you cannot use the `net.ifnames=0` kernel boot option for some reason, the same effect could be achieved with a `/etc/systemd/network/99-default.link` file, with the following contents:

```
[Match]

[Link]
NamePolicy=kernel
```

An empty `[Match]` section will match all devices, and setting `NamePolicy=kernel` uses the classic kernel-generated interface names like `eth0` or `wlan0`.

Note that in `/etc/systemd/network`, the alphanumerically first matching file wins, so by naming the file that matches every interface to `99-default.link`, you can still have the option to override specific interfaces by writing interface-specific link files, as long as you use a priority number smaller than 99 in the name of the file.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Just curious, why udev rule didn't work? and is there a way to make it consistent say i plug another wireless adapter and it automatically gets _wlan2_ .

Comment: The kernel still internally uses names like `eth0` and `wlan0`, and so the `KERNEL==` values in your rules were incorrect. Also, `net.ifnames=0` is a kernel boot option: it is not specific to GRUB. I'm not very familiar with systemd-boot, but after a quick browse through `systemd-boot` documentation, it seems to me that `/boot/loader/entries/*.conf` files could be used to persistently add kernel boot options.

Comment: Please see my edit for an alternative way to implement the effect of `net.ifnames=0`.

Comment: Ok I'll try, thanks for your time